# Android Fragments hide / remove / attach / detach / destroy

Tags: android, fragment, hide, detach

I'm completely stuck in the following problem.
I have a set of five `Fragments`.

`FragA` and `FragB` are always shown.
From an Options Menu with two entries I would like to: 
`menuEntryA`: show/add `FragC` and remove/hide/detatch `FragD` and `FragE`
`menuEntryB`: show/add `FragD` and `FragE` and remove/hide/detach `FragC`

The `Fragments` / classes can still exist, but they must not be shown.
All I reached is that a `Fragment` went white but it still occupies its place in the `Fragment` list, and when swiping through the `Fragments` forward an backward, it is there again.

After Starting the App
[image: After Starting]

After selecton optionsMenuA
[image: After optionsMenuA()]

After Swiping to the right and back
[image: After Swiping to the right and back]

Here is my code, please give me hints fill in the code that is necessary. I'm working on this for many hours and i didn't have any success.

```
    private void setupViewPager(CustomViewPager viewPager) {

   mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   fragA = new FrgA();   
   fragB = new FrgB(); 
   fragC = new FrgC(); 
   fragD = new FrgD(); 
   fragE = new FrgE(); 

   mAdapter.addFragment( fragA, getString(R.string.frag_title_A));
   mAdapter.addFragment( fragB, getString(R.string.frag_title_B));
   mAdapter.addFragment( fragC, getString(R.string.frag_title_C));
   mAdapter.addFragment( fragD, getString(R.string.frag_title_D));
   mAdapter.addFragment( fragE, getString(R.string.frag_title_E));

   viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
   viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> myFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> myFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
       super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return myFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < myFragmentList.size(); i++) {
           if (myFragmentList.get(i).getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fragment.getClass().getName())) {
              found = true;
           }
       }
       if (!found) {
          myFragmentList.add(fragment);
          myFragmentTitleList.add(title);
       }
     }

     @Override
     public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         return myFragmentTitleList.get(position);
     }

}


protected void optionsMenuA() {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.remove(fragCustomtext);
    //ft.detach(fragCustomtext);
    ft.commit();
    fm.popBackStack("null", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);


   //show/add FragC 

   //remove/hide/detatch FragD 

   //remove/hide/detatch FragE.

}

protected void optionsMenuB() {

   //show/add FragD

   //show/add FragE 

   //remove/hide/detatch FragC 

}

    <?xml encoding="utf-8"version="1.0"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eu.angermayr.test.MainActivity">

    <eu.angermayr.test.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />

    </eu.angermayr.test.CustomViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried setOffscreenPageLimit?

Comment: Please use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html Adapter, it will solve the 'blank fragment' issue

Comment: Not jet, my problem is that a fragment, once it is there, it wont disappear, no matter what i try.

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshots of the problem, so that we can understand it more specifically.

Comment: Done, here are the screenshots.